# Social.Framework deleted from project target BuildPhases

Tags: iphone, facebook, xcode4.5

I m doing Facebook integration with my project.But accidentally `Social.Framework` and `AdSupport.framework` got deleted from project's `Build Phases`.How can I get them back.Is there a way to add them externally ?

Comment: When I add these in project I get these ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/admin/App(1)/Social.framework/Social, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/admin/App(1)/Social.framework/Social (2 slices) and this error :  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:  objc-class-ref in FacebookSDK(FBUtility.o).Can u tell me what r these errors.When I add the social and Adsupport frameworks I get a ? in blue colour beside them ..Does it mean they r not added ?

Comment: Yes, I think you are not added these in proper way....

Comment: But I tried many times till now .I m adding them again and again but still I m gtng the error

Comment: GO to target - Link binary with with libraries & then click on any framework then right click & select show in finder you got a pop up window with all previous framework then just copy these framework & paste in pop up window..simple.then click on Link binary with with libraries you got your both framework then use it.

Comment: Thats fine ..Thank u once again..

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Trash, copy back those two frameworks, and paste them at you Framework path like:

`/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/6.0.1 (10A523)/Symbols/System/Library/Framework`

Past them both there.

Download these two Frameworks from below link:

http://www.sendspace.com/file/b0fifp